# Are there apps to split one big screen into multiple spaces?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, window-manager, spaces

I'm switching from three smaller screens to one big 42" monitor with Rectangle to emulate multiple monitors. It works great and I enjoy the flexibility in arranging the windows. However one thing missing is separate spaces. I used to have essential apps / documents on one 'main' monitor with others having multiple spaces. Now I have to switch the whole screen and have to go back and forth to find what I need. It's just a minor annoyance but I'm wondering are there apps to remedy this? By splitting one big screen into multiple smaller, virtual screens.

Answer (score 0):

I had one on Windows called gridview.exe and there is a similar one for iMac https://macgrid.app/ 1wk demo

https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/62836/grid $1.99   ? $5.99